# MembershipRequestWebPart Registration Error

Tags: 2010, forms-authentication

I've been setting up a local dev environment from a production SharePoint 2010 site and have got everything working except for the registration.  I've installed visigo.sharepoint.formsbasedauthentication.wsp and got the login working fine.  The registration is using the MembershipRequestWebPart.

After submitting the registration form, the same page is shown but the querystring is now showing ?ReturnUrl=%2f_layouts%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F%255Flayouts%252FAccessDenied%252Easpx&Source=%2F_layouts%2FAccessDenied%2Easpx

Using the ULS Viewer I see the following lines that are associated with the error:

> 03/07/2013 15:09:32.77    w3wp.exe (0x0B20)   0x0F58  SharePoint Foundation   General 8e2s    Medium  Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070002  35e65a3c-6d20-4bf2-8cf5-398847c2fc51
>
> 03/07/2013 15:09:33.61    w3wp.exe (0x0B20)   0x0F58  SharePoint Foundation   General 8e2s    Medium  Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070005  35e65a3c-6d20-4bf2-8cf5-398847c2fc51
>
> 03/07/2013 15:09:33.65    w3wp.exe (0x0B20)   0x0F58  SharePoint Foundation   General 8e2s    Medium  Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070002  35e65a3c-6d20-4bf2-8cf5-398847c2fc51
>
> 03/07/2013 15:09:33.65    w3wp.exe (0x0B20)   0x0F58  SharePoint Foundation   General 8e2s    Medium  Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070002  35e65a3c-6d20-4bf2-8cf5-398847c2fc51
>
> 03/07/2013 15:09:33.72    w3wp.exe (0x0B20)   0x0F58  SharePoint 2010 FBA Pack    General 0000    High    System.Exception: Thread was being aborted.     at Visigo.Sharepoint.FormsBasedAuthentication.MembershipRequest.ApproveMembership(MembershipRequest request, SPWeb web) 35e65a3c-6d20-4bf2-8cf5-398847c2fc51
>
> 03/07/2013 15:09:33.73    w3wp.exe (0x0B20)   0x0F58  SharePoint 2010 FBA Pack    General 0000    High    System.Exception: Thread was being aborted.     at Visigo.Sharepoint.FormsBasedAuthentication.MembershipRequest.ApproveMembership(MembershipRequest request, SPWeb web)     at Visigo.Sharepoint.FormsBasedAuthentication.MembershipRequestControl.b__0()    35e65a3c-6d20-4bf2-8cf5-398847c2fc51
>
> 03/07/2013 15:09:33.74    w3wp.exe (0x0B20)   0x0F58  Web Content Management  Publishing  7fov    Medium  Caught a thread abort exception in TemplateRedirectionPage.ProcessRequest, the exception may be expected. stack trace=   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at ASP.LOGINPAGELAYOUT_ASPX_190343958.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    35e65a3c-6d20-4bf2-8cf5-398847c2fc51

I've checked the aspnet_Users and aspnet_Membership tables and the user is not inserted in either.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

**Update**

When I am logged in and try to register using the same existing page or a new page that just has the MembershipRequestWebPart on it, after submitting I am taken to the /_layouts/AccessDenied.aspx page, but this time it actually displays that page. What I'm confused about it what it is trying to access on the post back that it isn't during the initial display of the page? I'm still seeing the same errors in the logs with thread being abort at the ApproveMembership call.

Also, I have done a database backup from the live site to create my local site, so any configuration of SharePoint that is in the SQL database will have been moved over to my local dev environment.  I did redeploy all of the wsp files locally and had to recreate the public site on port 80 to use Claims Authentication since when I first installed SP locally I didn't select that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replicate the zone in local same as the Live site. Once you extend the site it will create a new iis site on webserver. So you need to go and check again and compare the web.config for both the webapps. compare the web.config for default zone both in local and live sites. Same applies to internet zone. Also make the changes to the web.config in dev related to the questioned webparts safe controls make it same as live.

Comment: I will try this first thing in the morning.  Thank you so much.

Comment: I extended the site to add the Internet zone without Anonymous access, and added the intranet site with anonymous access, just like my live site is setup for.  And then I copied the entire <SafeControls> section from the live port 80 web.config to the local port 80 web.config and now the registration worked.  I'm not sure which change made it happen but one of them fixed it.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Looks like I can't give you the bounty for another 9 hours so I'll be back to take care of that.  Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Does the registration web part work properly if added to a standard SharePoint page and the user is logged in? If that's the case, it probably has something to do with how the web part is made available anonymously:

If you are just using a standard SharePoint page in a library with anonymous access, likely there's some content in your master page that does not have anonymous access and is causing the redirect to authenticate.aspx.

If you have added the web part to an anonymous application page (http://sharepoint2010fba.codeplex.com/discussions/259533) then likely there is either content in your master page that does not have anonymous access (use "simple.master" to resolve), or it's missing the AllowAnonymousAccess/AllowNullWeb settings or is not inheriting from UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.

Comment: Thanks.  When I am logged in and try to register using the same existing page or a new page that just has the MembershipRequestWebPart on it, after submitting I am taken to the /_layouts/AccessDenied.aspx page, but this time it actually displays that page.  What I'm confused about it what it is trying to access on the post back that it isn't during the initial display of the page?  I'm still seeing the same errors in the logs with thread being abort at the ApproveMembership call.

Comment: Also I should mention that this local site is basically a clone of a live site that is working.  So the databases are exactly the same.  This leads me to believe that it is a setting somewhere on the server, or something to do with how I deployed all the wsps locally, or how I setup the authentication provider for the public site when creating it and then attaching the backup of the database.

Comment: Check the web.config file settings for that web application under inetpub and compare it with the production version. can you pls check its not anonymouse access turned-on on this web app. Can you also turnon and off the ViewFormPagesLockdown feature on that sitecollection.

Comment: Web.config of local vs live, only differences is that the live site has a <browsercaps> section, and some of the <SafeControl> elements have Safe="true" on the live site and not on the local site.

I compared the live and local sites and checked to see if ViewFormsPafgesLockdown feature was enabled and it is not enabled on both sites.

Anonymous access is turned on for Claims Based Auth on both sites.  I did noticed that the live site has a default and internet zones and the internet one doesn't have anonymous access, while the default does.  The local site only has a default zone.